# Sockets: PHP Client, PY Server returns error 111 [connection refused]

Tags: python, php, sockets

I've setup a python -> python socket client/server connection without any problems.

I now want to move the client onto a website with php so that I can communicate with the python server from the website. When using the python -> python server, everything is fine however when I replicate the same setup with the php client on my website and the server on my vps (bare in mind the server was already on my vps), the php returns error 111.

client.php

```
$host = 'my.ip.of.vps';

// create socket
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

// connect to server
if(!socket_connect($sock, $host, 8080))
{
    echo 'Failed at socket_connect with error: ' . socket_last_error(); 
}

socket_close($sock);
```

server.py

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = 'my.ip.of.vps'
port = 8080
s.bind((host,port))

while True:
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("RECEIVED CONNECTION:", addr)
```

Any suggestions/fixes/help would be really appreciated!

Comment: is this a new website you're creating? If so why not just write it with python?

Comment: @Adyson Preferabbly I'd like it to be in php since the website is a forum from phpBB. It would be much easier in php.